# Open source applications for the Lift web framework

Tags: scala, open-source, lift

I'm looking for open source applications written for the Lift Web framework. I want to read their code, and learn the best Lift-ish coding style from those.

Anyone knows good open source Lift web applications?

Comment: Does anybody know about larger applications? Toy projects like these only get you so far...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might have a look at:
http://github.com/rmuri/TravelCompanionScala

The interesting thing here is, that it uses JPA instead of the Lift Mapper. For many shops this might ease the "oh everything is new" shock when moving to Scala/Lift.

FYI an updated version of this sample app can be found here:

https://github.com/dhobi/TravelCompanionScala

Features:

- Designer Friendly Templates
- Updated to Scala 2.10.0, Lift 2.5-M4

Answer (score 5):

I recently downloaded pocketchangeapp from http://github.com/tjweir/pocketchangeapp. A simple application runs in Scala 2.0 by Derek Chen-Becker, very useful for learning from existing code.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily paradigmatic, but Lift Poker is wicked cool: http://poker.dhobi.staxapps.net/ http://github.com/dhobi/LiftPoker

Answer (score 1):

[Lift samples](http://github.com/dpp/lift-samples) is a good place to start

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the list. One prominent example is Apaches ESME.

http://github.com/apache/esme

A good starting point is println.io (a blogging software written with the lift framework)